# LCD identification & repair

Tags: identification, components, lcd

Afternoon all,

I am trying to repair a Mcculloch robotic mower which has (what I presume to be) a broken LCD screen. As per the photos the screen is just showing garbled lines. I'm hoping that identifying and replacing the LCD unit will do the trick and that it isn't actually the logic on the board that's knackered. The board itself is a '588 44 19-01 REV.A MMI' as used in various Husqvarna based machines.

Details of the LCD are as follows:
*The glass measures 55mm x 37mm
*Screen area 52mm x 29mm
*2.5mm thickness
*Plastic mount 57mm x 39.5mm
*18 pins on short 16mm wide central ribbon cable
*only markings are 'GE-1 94V-0 1 1633' on the ribbon and 'TX1571700' on the mount

If anyone can offer assistance in identifying the unit, or indeed what may be the issue I would be most grateful!

Many thanks,
A very hunble FlyingElk

[image: board pin connectors]

[image: LCD unit]

[image: ribbon markings]

[image: LCD display]

Comment: This is not an engineering question, it has more chances in a repair forum

Comment: This is a valid process engineering EE question for those who work in the PCB assembly workforce as process , industrial or electrical techs. Newbies need to know #1 fault in assembly is solder defects. (Open, short, intermittent) take note who disagree, let me know.

Comment: These sorts of screens are often easier to find as complete modules with all the logic and controller chips integrated, rather than the bare LCD alone. It may be easier to just look for a complete replacement board than just the LCD.

Answer (score 0):

If you re-insert the FPC into the connect, see if it changes. Vibration may have shifted it or something is oxidized.

While operating, Then press with finger on each component to look for open solder joints. #1 failure mode. Then inspect for shorts on all joints with a magnifier lens. #2 fault.

Comment: As the pictures show, the FPC is soldered to the board, so the first point doesn't apply. Looking for cracked solder joints or shorts is always a reasonable suggestion though.

Comment: Based on how the display looks, there is a problem between LCD matrix in the glass and the LCD driver chip mounted on the glass or flex. It would be hard to explain the symptoms on screen just by saying the flex between MCU and display driver is broken or needs resoldering. Likely flex itself and flex soldering to MCU PCB is fine.

Comment: It would be easy if the LCD bias voltages had noise on them from missing cap connections, @jens are you sure it is soldered at LCD?Still, solder accounts for 99% of all mfg faults for most low -tech PCA's such as this. I used to be Eng Mgr at C-MAC so this is validated .

Comment: Thanks all for your replies. I've checked continuity on all joints and it appears to be an issue with the screen itself or with the ribbon cable - I'm unable to test this specifically as the screen control logic etc is all encapsulated in resin. May have to try and source a board but will need to find out how to reprogram it.